# Cannot create file on ubuntu bash shell in my window machine

Tags: linux, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

when I was try to use  **touch** command on my ubuntu bash shell and in my Desktop folder **/mnt/c/Users/Public/Desktop$** it give me this **touch: cannot touch 'test.txt': Permission denied** error.

Comment: What does `ls -l /mnt/c/Users` show? And if there is a problem, check the mount as well `mount | grep '/mnt/c'` to insure the mount is present. Lastly, I’m voting to close this question because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange site [Super User](http://superuser.com/). You can migrate the question there for more help with WSL.

Comment: mount | grep '/mnt/c'  show me this "C:\ on /mnt/c type drvfs (rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,case=off)" output. And sorry for that question but this is my first day in linux environment  and many of linux terminology very strange for me.

Comment: The filesystem is mounted so you are good there. What is the `'$'` at the end of `Desktop$` -- isn't is just `Desktop`? Also what about the output to `ls -l /mnt/c/Users` and `ls -l /mnt/c/Users/Public`? Does the latter actually show a `Desktop$` directory below `Public`? Also recall Linux is case-sensitive. So make sure windows actually uses the capital letters  in the path. Easiest way is just start listing directories from `/mnt/c` on. First `ls -al /mnt/c` do you see `Users`. The `ls -al /mnt/c/Users` -- do you see `Public` and so on.

Comment: I will easily navigate to the desktop directory but when I try to use "touch test.txt" command It gives me "touch: cannot touch 'test.txt': Permission denied" error. and ( I don't know why this $ sign is at the end of my Desktop but it is my desktop directory ) - And when I try to execute "ls -l /mnt/c/Users" command it show me all available directory in my Users folder

Comment: Yes, I booted Win10 and checked, default permissions on `/mnt/c/Users/Public/Desktop` are read and execute only (e.g. `dr-xr-xr-x`). You need to do a `chmod +w mnt/c/Users/Public/Desktop` and then once you have write permission, you can write to the directory.

Comment: It will work on run as administration window but  after  run that `chmod +w /mnt/c/Users/Public/Desktop `  command my problem will remain the same in normal window but in administration window I will able to create directories and files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not have access to the /mnt/c/Users/Public/Desktop directory as default

Run:

```
ls -ld /c/mnt/Users/Public/Desktop
```

to see whether you have write permissions as default. If you don't run:

```
sudo chmod +w /mnt/c/Users/Public/Desktop
```

This will then allow you write permissions to the directory and allow you to create files.

NOTE - Please ensure that the initial bash executable is run as administrator at Windows level

Comment: But I still give that same error when I will try to make file within Desktop folder with touch command.

Comment: @ultralordps you need to make sure that the initial bash executable is runs as the administrator. I have added a note to the solution